# Angularjs directive inside directive

Tags: angularjs

I have two directives, `resource` and `formajax`. Here they are:

Resource

**resource.coffee** (partial)

```
    (...)
    ($http, $location, $compile) ->
        restrict: "E"
        templateUrl: templateUrl
        scope:
          action: "@"
        transclude: true

        link: (scope, element, attributes) ->
          (...)
```

**resource.html**

```
<div class="resource">
    <style type="text/css">
        .resource .new-record {
            padding: 10px;
        }
    </style>
    <button class="button" ng-click="addRecord()">+ Dodaj wiadomość</button>
    <div class="new-record" ng-show="showAddForm">
        <formajax action="{{action}}" />
    </div>

    <div ng-transclude></div>

</div>
```

And formajax

**formajax.coffee** (partial)

```
    (...)
    ($http, $location) ->
        restrict: "E"
        scope:
            action: "@"
            title: "@"
            formStatus: "="
            additionalFields: "="
            onData: "&"

        templateUrl: templateUrl

        link: (scope, element, attributes) ->
            (...)
```

**formajax.html**

```
<form method="post" action="{{action}}" role="form" class="form-ajax">
    <fieldset>
        <legend>{{title}}</legend>
        <div ng-bind-html-unsafe="form"></div>
        <button type="button" ng-click="submit()" class="btn button">Wyślij</button>
    </fieldset>
</form>
```

## Bootstrapping

And that's how I start everything up:

```
<resource action="/api/messages/">
```

And the problem is, that `action` isn't passed to `formajax` at linking time, there is `undefined` instead of `/api/messages/`. It I `$watch` `scope.action` inside `resource`, it is available eventually, but I suppose it's bound later, too late to link `formajax` with desirable value.
Maybe `templateUrl` and asynchronous loading couses problems, makes some binding impossible or unhandled?

Comment: Have you tried to use only scope.action in the formajax instead of passing as scope variable directly to the directive? Also probably you can remove {{action}} from the html directive and try it again.

Comment: I cannot remove `{{ }}` in formajax.html, because the string will be treated literally.

Comment: And `formajax` works well if it's placed directly in some controller, this problem happens inside other directive.

Answer (score 0):

I think you could try by passing the controller of the parent directive to the child, the values will be bound at the same time in both directives. I made an example here : http://jsfiddle.net/DotDotDot/pVYL6/3/ (I couldn't use your code so I used something shorter)

Actually, I added a controller to the first directive (your `resource`directive) where I define some getters :

```
.directive('parent',function(){
return {
    scope:{action:'@'},
    controller: function($scope, $element, $attrs) {
       this.getAction=function(){
           return $scope.action; 
        }
    }   
}
});
```

The directive gets the action in the parameters, and this action can be accessed by `getAction()`. I use `this` instead of `$scope` because the goal is to use the controller in another directive. You can still add all your code of the `resource` directive, just add a getter in the controller.
Then, in the child directive, your `formajax`, you will require the parent directive controller, and pass it in the link function :

```
....
    require:'^parent',
    link:function(scope, elt, attr, parentCtrl){
        scope.$watch(function(){
            scope.childaction=parentCtrl.getAction()
        });
```

Edit : you still have to $watch the changes
Now you can access all your values from the parent directive in the child one

I hope this will help you,

Have fun

Comment: thanks, but your example seems to be working even without controller.

Comment: Oooops ! Indeed, I forgot to edit my message, it worked only because it was the same name in both directives. I edit my message with the good version of the code

Answer (score 0):

I got mad and did something like this:

```
    ($http, $location, $compile) ->
        restrict: "E"
        templateUrl: templateUrl
        scope:
          action: "@"
        transclude: true

        link:
          pre: (scope, element, attributes) ->
            scope.action = attributes.action

          post: (scope, element, attributes) ->
            scope.form = $compile("""<formajax action="#{scope.action}" />""") scope

            scope.showAddForm = false
            scope.addRecord = ->
              scope.showAddForm = true
```

Hacky, but works ;)